# django Multiple object mixins with get method

Tags: django

May be someone know, can i use Multiple object mixins with get method in my view? I understand that i need to specify queryset. But can i do this from method?

```
class Search(MultipleObjectMixin, View):

paginate_by = 2

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    products = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=name)
    self.queryset = products
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'main_list': products,
                  'category_list': category, 'name': name,
                  'matches': len(products)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution to what you are trying to accomplish is going to be to use a `TemplateView` or a `ListView` you are effectively not even using the `MultipleObjectMixin` in your example.

Here is an example with just a `TemplateView` without paging

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search_results.thml'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        name = self.request.GET.get('name', '')
        products = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=name)
        context['main_list'] = products
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['name'] = name
        context['matches'] = products.count()
        return context
```

Here is an example with a `ListView`, which I recommend since it uses the `MultipleObjectMixin` with it, but saves you some work.

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'main_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['name'] = self.request.GET.get('name', '')
        context['matches'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        name = self.request.GET.get('name', '')
        return qs.filter(name__contains=name)
```

You can even go a step further and create a `CategoryMixin` so you can inherit it in other views so you just add it in to get a list of categories

```
class CategoryMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class SearchView(CategoryMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'main_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['name'] = self.request.GET.get('name', '')
        context['matches'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        name = self.request.GET.get('name', '')
        return qs.filter(name__contains=name)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm usually using ListView, but form get request confused me!